# How can I import ova file to vcenter using vcenter api?

Tags: go, vcenter

I am trying to upload ova file to vcenter library using REST API.
To do this ( all are done using Vcenter api)

1. Auth using
2. Get datastore
3. Created Library
4. Added Item to library
5. Created update session
6. Get Endpoint for uploading
7. Upload ova file to vcenter

Stage 1 ~ 6 are succesfully done, but last stage i can not upload ova file to vcenter library.
When I call the api, it returns 200 resp code and it seems like that uploading finished successfully. But, in fact, I couldn't find out any ova file imported on vcenter library and I could see the error "Error detected parsing header"

My upload function is below;

```
func UploadFile(client *http.Client, fileName, uploadEndpoint, sessionID string) (status bool, err error) {

file, err := os.Open(fileName)
if err != nil {
    return false, err
}
defer file.Close()

body := &bytes.Buffer{}
writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("file", filepath.Base(fileName))
if err != nil {
    return false, err
}
_, err = io.Copy(part, file)

err = writer.Close()
if err != nil {
    return false, err
}
//uploadEndpoint ;  https://ip252.ip-51-255-152.eu:443/cls/data/5a86158a-f818-4796-8bc1-e4d88a29dcd7/focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uploadEndpoint, body)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
req.Header.Set("vmware-api-session-id", sessionID)

resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return false, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

return true, nil
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm trying to do exactly the same thing right now.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but [I made a script](https://github.com/bluechipgit/PowerCLI/blob/main/scripts/Deploy-Templates/Deploy-Templates.ps1) that takes a selected OVA, pushes it to a specified vCenter, then converts it to a template using PowerCLI. You may find parts of it useful.

Comment: Answers need to complete, even if a link dies in the future. This means that you need to include the key points from your linked code into the body of the answer.

Comment: It sounds like the key points *are* included in the body of the answer.